# When using SendKeys()-InvalidOperationException: Undo Operation encountered

Tags: c#, sendkeys, invalidoperationexception

Here is my code

```
public void KeyPress()
    {
        //Finds the target window and sends a key command to the application
        Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("calc");
        IntPtr calculatorHandle;
        foreach (Process proc in processes)
        {
            calculatorHandle = proc.MainWindowHandle;

            if (calculatorHandle == IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Calculator is not running.");
                return;
            }
            SetForegroundWindow(calculatorHandle);

            break;
        }

        SendKeys.SendWait("1");

    }
```

After Executing this code I recieve an Error, i know the source is the SendKeys.

Here is the full error I am Receiving

```
System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled
  Message="The Undo operation encountered a context that is different from what was applied in the corresponding Set operation. The possible cause is that a context was Set on the thread and not reverted(undone)."
  Source="mscorlib"
  StackTrace:
       at System.Threading.SynchronizationContextSwitcher.Undo()
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContextSwitcher.Undo()
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.runFinallyCode(Object userData, Boolean exceptionThrown)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.ExecuteBackoutCodeHelper(Object backoutCode, Object userData, Boolean exceptionThrown)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup(TryCode code, CleanupCode backoutCode, Object userData)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Net.ContextAwareResult.Complete(IntPtr userToken)
       at System.Net.LazyAsyncResult.ProtectedInvokeCallback(Object result, IntPtr userToken)
       at System.Net.Sockets.BaseOverlappedAsyncResult.CompletionPortCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* nativeOverlapped)
       at System.Threading._IOCompletionCallback.PerformIOCompletionCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* pOVERLAP)
  InnerException:
```

I'm not sure what the problem is, The number will appear in my calculator but that error pops up

Comment: This error has nothing to do with `SendKeys`.  What is the `InnerException`? Are you doing any asynchronous IO?

Comment: Are using Sockets for anything in the application? It seems that the problem related to the completion of an async socket operation.

Comment: @SLaks- I believe we are using asynchronous I/O. The InnerException is NULL.

@Chris- Yes we are using sockets, passing a variable to trigger the function. The application on a button press on the command station, will trigger the function on a client. And use the sendkeys to simulate a button press in the application on the client.

Need any more info?

Comment: Where is `KeyPress` being called?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, so based on your response to my question I will make 2 assumptions.

1. You are calling KeyPress from a function that is being executed asynchronously, possibly from the callback of a BeginReceive or something similar.
2. Your application is a windows forms application.

If the above assumptions are correct then I suspect that the problem is with the fact that SendKeys using windows messaging internally and the problem is occurring because the SendkKeys messages are being sent from a thread other than the UI thread. If this is correct, you might be able to resolve the problem by using [Control.Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b.aspx) to make the call to the KeyPress function. Using `Control.Invoke` will marshal the call back to the UI thread.

Comment: I had to use Control.Invoke Method (Delegate, Object[])
I have one other programmer working on the project, and the Control.Invoke coupled with a private delegate has got the program working

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I had a play with this myself and couldn't replicate it.

Did a google search and found the folllowing article which has quite a few suggestions, which you might like to try. 
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/netfxbcl/thread/48b4a763-7387-46da-8fc2-3e885670f62c

Of course, you may have already looked there, which is why you came here.

You may need to provide more broad information on context in which you are calling the code. What is the prupose of the app, how does this fit in? Can you tell what line of code its failing on?

Also, as @SLaks suggested, can you include more details on the inner exception?

Comment: +1 for the link to the thread. Though there were other related threads on social.msdn.microsoft.com, none compare to the link provided. Thanks.